# In C, fopen() is working from IDE (Xcode), but won't open file in Terminal (Mac)

Tags: c, fopen

I'm new and learning C.  My code works perfectly when running in IDE (Xcode).  fopen() opens the file inName.dat - parses the characters - and outputs to the two outName files and stdout - as expected.

But when I try to run the program from Terminal (I use a Mac) - the file inName.dat won't open.

I've tried replacing the pointer in the fopen() call with a direct file name "inName.dat" - but it still won't open - when run in Terminal.

All three files inName.dat, outName1.dat and outName.dat2 exist and are in the same file as the application files.

I know the error is at the point the file is being opened - I've added the printed error message there to be sure.

```
/* My main application */

int main() {
    char *inFileName;
    char *outFileName1 = "outName1.dat";
    char *outFileName2 = "outName2.dat";

    if((inFileName = calloc(25, sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failure allocating memory\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Enter filename to split: \n");
    scanf("%s", inFileName);

    split(inFileName, outFileName1, outFileName2);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/* My implementation file */

int split(const char* inName, const char* outName1, const char*
    outName2) {
    FILE *inFile;
    FILE *outFile1;
    FILE *outFile2;
    char *inBuffer;
    char *outBuffer1;
    char *outBuffer2;
    char *stdoutBuff;
    int out1, out2, outstd;

    /* open three files */
    if((inFile = fopen(inName, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("The error is here"); /* Prints, then app ends */
        return 0;
    }
    if((outFile1 = fopen(outName1, "w")) == NULL) {
        fclose(inFile);
        return 0;
    }
    if((outFile2 = fopen(outName2, "w")) == NULL) {
        fclose(inFile);
        fclose(outFile1);
        return 0;
    }

    /* allocate memory to buffers */
    if((inBuffer = calloc(500, sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Inbuffer memory allocation error\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if((outBuffer1 = calloc(500, sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Outbuffer1 memory allocation error\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if((outBuffer2 = calloc(500, sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Outbuffer2 memory allocation error\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if((stdoutBuff = calloc(500, sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stdoutbuffer memory allocation error\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* read in from input file to inBuffer */
    if(fgets(inBuffer, 500, inFile) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Input from file error\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* sort each letter to out buffers as lower/uppercase/other */
    for(out1 = 0, out2 = 0, outstd = 0; *inBuffer; inBuffer++) {
        if(islower(inBuffer[0])) {
            outBuffer1[out1] = inBuffer[0];
            out1++;
        } else if(isupper(inBuffer[0])) {
            outBuffer2[out2] = inBuffer[0];
            out2++;
        } else {
            stdoutBuff[outstd] = inBuffer[0];
            outstd++;
        }
    }

    /* print the out buffers to file 1,2 and stdout */
    if(fputs(outBuffer1, outFile1) == EOF) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(fputs(outBuffer2, outFile2) == EOF) {
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Non lower / uppercase letters from file:\n");
    if(fputs(stdoutBuff, stdout) == EOF) {
        return 0;
    }  
    return 1;
}
```

No crash or error message - it just prints my line "The error is here", then returns 0 to main, which ends the program.

Comment: Check the `errno` after `fopen`. Use `perror` to print a descriptive message. My bet would be that the working directory is not what you think and it simply can't find this file.

Comment: Try an absolute path to the file, like `/Users/ashepherd/myfolder/inName.dat`. If that works, it supports the hypothesis that the working directory is different in the IDE than in the Terminal, as is quite likely.

Comment: How are you running your program in the terminal? What's the exact command you're using?

Comment: Problem solved.  I had the file in the same directory as my executable code - which had always worked in the past.  Using the absolute path revealed where it was actually looking for the file - which was in fact in a different directory.  No idea why it was looking there - but it solved my problem.  Thanks!